# Joomla 3.3 - How to store user password?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i'm trying to store user password in a plugin using joomla 3.3.6.

According to Joomla Documentation : https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

I created the following function :

```
    /**
 * 
 * Update Password
 * 
 * @param unknown $idUser
 * @param unknown $password
 */
public function updateUserPassword($idUser, $password) {

    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $this->db->getQuery ( true );
    $value = JUserHelper::hashPassword($password);

    // Prepare the insert query.
    $query->update('#__users')
        ->set('password  = ' . $this->db->quote($value))
        ->where('id = ' . $idUser);

    // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
    $this->db->setQuery ($query);

    $updateResult = $this->db->execute ();
    if ($updateResult == false) {
        $errorMsg = $this->db->getErrorMsg ();
        var_dump($errorMsg);
    } else {
        echo "Update Done";
    }   
}
```

This code is executed without any error or warning but the user record in table users remains unchanged.

$query value is  :

```
UPDATE #__users
SET password  = '$2y$10$hO2MfDLfG5ICy2yhZWXZG.GCQ89vYw26KHVisXuuD8baRU9WtuDR.'
WHERE id = 192
```

$query looks fine. Executing the query in mysqlworkbench by replacing #__ with my custom db prefix returns ok and i can see changes in db.

However the php code doesn't work.

Anyone have a clue about this ?

Dev.

**EDIT**
Code Change : Adding error handling in execute statement.
The message "Update Done" is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code snippet, I don't see how you've determined that the code is executing without any error.

From the Joomla documentation
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_execute
your execute statement should have a return value of either a cursor or false.

```
$updateResult = $this->db->execute();
if($updateResult == false) {
    $errorMsg = $this->db->getErrorMsg();
    //display this in your method of choice
}
```

Depending on your server, there may also be an web server error log entry.  On my LAMP development machine, it's in /var/log/apache2/error_log

Alternate method to modify a Joomla table record

```
$user_record = new stdClass();
$user_record->id = $idUser;
$user_record->password = $password;

$result = JFactory::getDbo()->insertObject('#__users', $user_record, $idUser);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my post with your code error handling. $updateResult is equal to true in my test case. Apache log is empty when i execute my function.

Comment: @Dev  Sorry then.  Anything else I'd suggest would be grasping at straws.  There is an alternate method to update an object that I'll put in my answer.  It just seems unlikely to make a difference.  I'm sure you've double checked this, but I'll ask anyways...have you tried your function with some sort of test password instead of the function $password?

Comment: Problem Solved : The code in my question was working well. Problem was on an other function which update an other time my user object. Thanks for help and your time.